# iTextSharp button (pdf) doesn't work on Edge

Tags: itext

We developed an Asp.net web application (6-7 years ago), which generates pdf fillable forms dynamically, based on a template using iTextSharp, and display it inside the browser. This pdf fillable form(iTextsharp submitForm) has a submit button(also created with itextSharp-getPushButton). When user clicks on this button, the script behind the button submit(post) the form.
This application was working just fine for years using IE 11 using IE pdf plugin.
Recently, we upgraded to Microsoft Edge, which like Chrome, has its own, built-in pdf viewer, and the button for posting(submitting) the form stopped working. Button is there, on pdf form, but does not do anything when clicked. I found few resources saying this is because Chrome/Edge do not allow script from pdf embedded button to run. If it is not possible to run the script/code from pdf form inside Edge/Chrome, is there another way to accomplish this? We have an option to run Edge in IE mode, but this is not a long term solution.
Any ideas?
Thank you,
Goran